# Can't properly deserialize a json with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using an API to get football data and I am having trouble deserializing the JSON that I get from the API. The JSON looks like this:

```json
\`\`
`{"current":1,"total":1}, "response": [{"league":{"id":4,"name":"Euro C`hampionship","type":"Cup","logo":"https://media-2.api-sports.io/football/leagues/4.png"},"country":{"name":"World","code":null,"flag":null}`,"seasons":[{"year":2008,"start":"2008-06-07","end":"2008-06-29","current":false,"coverage":{"fixtures":{"events":true,"lineups":true,"statistics_fixtures":false,"statistics_players":false},"standings":false,"players":true,"top_scorers":true,"top_assists":true,"top_cards":true,"injuries":false,"predictions":true,"odds":false}},{"year":2012,"start":"2012-06-08","end":"2012-07-01","current":false,"coverage":{"fixtures":{"events":true,"lineups":true,"statistics_fixtures":false,"statistics_players":false},"standings":false,"players":true,"top_scorers":true,"top_assists":true,"top_cards":true,"injuries":false,"predictions":true,"odds":false}},{"year":2016,"start":"2016-06-10","end":"2016-07-10","current":false,"coverage":{"fixtures":{"events":true,"lineups":true,"statistics_fixtures":true,"statistics_players":true},"standings":true,"players":true,"top_scorers":true,"top_assists":true,"top_cards":true,"injuries":false,"predictions":true,"odds":false}},{"year":2020,"start":"2019-03-21","end":"2021-07-11","current":true,"coverage":{"fixtures":{"events":true,"lineups":true,"statistics_fixtures":true,"statistics_players":true},"standings":true,"players":true,"top_scorers":true,"top_assists":true,"top_cards":true,"injuries":false,"predictions":true,"odds":false}}]}`
```

I want to get the ID of each league, as well as its name and logo. I have created the following classes:

```
public class FootballCountryModel
{
[JsonProperty("id")\]
public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("logo")]
    public string Logo { get; set; }

}

public class Results
{

    [JsonProperty("league")]
    public Dictionary<string, FootballCountryModel> JsonResults { get; set; }

}

public class JsonRootObject
{
[JsonProperty("response")\]
public Results Rslt { get; set; }
}

public class LeaguesDeserializedModel
{
[JsonProperty("parameters")\]
public object Parameters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public object Errors { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public int Results { get; set; }
    
    
    [JsonProperty("paging")]
    public object Pagin { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public List<FootballCountryModel> Response { get; set; }
    }
```

and then I use this line to deserialize the JSON:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(response.Content);
```

It will be highly appreciated if someone can tell me the ideology behind how to deserialize such complex(for me) JSONS.

I am trying to deserialize a JSON with Newtonsoft, but I am struggling to do it.

Comment: json you posted is not valid, pls post the real one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please use this link as the json is too long - https://pastebin.com/XX0RDCNE

Comment: "Please use this link as the json is too long" - no, please reduce your example to a [mcve]. We shouldn't have to wade through 60K of JSON to find what's not working - that's part of the work *you* should do in terms of diagnostics before asking a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the future , if you want to get the right answer in the right time, you have to post a correct json string at least( people should not waste their time trying to parse a wrong json string), or (it is not usually recommended) a link if the json string is really large and very complicated and it is hard to create a demo string.

If you don't need all data, but only part of it, you have to parse  your json string and after this select the part you need and deserialize only this part.
In your question, if you need only FootballCountryModelList it could be

```
List<FootballCountryModel> list = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["response"]
                        .Select(x => x["league"].ToObject<FootballCountryModel>())
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed. I have never deserialize an object, especially so complicated(in my opinion) and I need some clarification of how the logic goes. Can you give me a link from where I can read how to proceed when deserializing.

Comment: @LyuboWorking Unfortunatelly you can just learn  how to use a json in minutes. There are plenty tutorials,  you just google. Or if you fill comfortable with json alreday you can read Newtonsoft.Json documentation https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

Answer (score -1):

Here is the structure of Model classes for your JSON. You may add desired JsonProperty attributes & give your names to the properties:

Here is how you can deserialize the Root object.

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
```

Following are the Model classes for your complex JSON structure:

```
public class Country
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
}

public class Coverage
{
    public Fixtures fixtures { get; set; }
    public bool standings { get; set; }
    public bool players { get; set; }
    public bool top_scorers { get; set; }
    public bool top_assists { get; set; }
    public bool top_cards { get; set; }
    public bool injuries { get; set; }
    public bool predictions { get; set; }
    public bool odds { get; set; }
}

public class Fixtures
{
    public bool events { get; set; }
    public bool lineups { get; set; }
    public bool statistics_fixtures { get; set; }
    public bool statistics_players { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public League league { get; set; }
    public Country country { get; set; }
    public List<Season> seasons { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string get { get; set; }
    public List<object> parameters { get; set; }
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
    public int results { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}

public class Season
{
    public int year { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public bool current { get; set; }
    public Coverage coverage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience. I had now idea how to present the JSON data.